# CK Editor and Firefox 33 conflict

Tags: firefox, ckeditor

Today, I open my website which use CKEditor.
I encounter a strange behavior. In any page that has CKEditor, jquery click event listener seems to not work.

This is odd. I have try to open the same website in chrome and firefox 32 with no problem.

I even try to visit CKEditor website to make sure that this problem is not caused by my script.
And I can ensure that the problem is occurred exactly as in my website. CKEditor has javascript based menu, if you click "Full featured" link, the element on the left-side should be changed with respective element. But it doesn't response as it should be. (Just for the record, this website also works fine in chrome and firefox 32)

I have also use firebug to find any helping-error-message, but I can't find any error message there.

I am sure this must be firefox's bug. Hopefully they will fix this in firefox 34.
[image: Click event doesn't work]

However, does anybody experience the same problem? Is there any workaround for this?

**UPDATE :** Seems that this problem is caused by plugin (firePHP or fireQuery). Look at the comments for more information.

Comment: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0`. It works just fine. Tried different OSs? Browser addons?

Comment: @oleq: thanks, I have firebug, firephp, firequery and yslow, I remove everything and it seems to work. Still wonder which plugin cause the trouble. Why don't you put your comment as answer so that I can accept it?